# Broken boolean search in Acrobat XI

Tags: pdf, search, adobe-acrobat

I am using Adobe Acrobat Pro XI. I can't seem to be able to use a boolean search in the Advanced Find. I know it has worked before but just can't do it now.

```
CTRL-SHIFT-F to bring up advanced find.
Search in current document
Search for: "both may" OR "manually as specified"
Whole words only, case sensitivity, include bookmarks/comments are all OFF.
```

Zero results even though I can see both phrases on the first page. What am I doing wrong?

~AGP

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the Advanced Find but in "Look In" I had to choose the **FOLDER** where the PDF was located and then in "Return results containing: Boolean query". Then I could use the search

```
both may OR manually as specified
```

Not sure why Adobe doesn't allow this on a single PDF.